# Hashtag in tabs-page jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

Just wondering. How I can make this tabs-page-script so when I click in my menu it will be a hashtag? How can I make my div's so it will be http://mypage.se/#onediv

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); 

    $("ul.tabs a").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
        $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: [Fragment identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) are not [hashtags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtag)

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is you have tabs in a ul like

```
<a ... > Tab1 </a>
```

Then you can simply add

```
<a href='#tab1'>Tab1</a>
```

And it will change the url and append the desired hash.